# Triple for loop with arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get string with specific value. The issue is with FIND_IN_SET, because `$find_demographics` doesn't work propely if is outside for loop with `$j`. Also If I try to move `$$demographics_values` to the `$j` for loop, then names for values doesn't work.

It's not important what is inside `user_about` or `m_z_analytics`, because I only want to insert right value inside FIND_IN_SET in `$$demographics_values` string.

PS. How I could change the code to get the fastest response for 5.6 version?

**Sample expectations for `$$demographics_values` string:**

```
$g_demographics_value_1 = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('a01', b.about_education)");
...
$g_demographics_value_18 = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('b01', b.about_personal)");
$g_demographics_value_19 = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('b02', b.about_personal)");
$g_demographics_value_20 = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('c01', b.about_personal)");
$g_demographics_value_21 = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('c02', b.about_personal)");
$g_demographics_value_22 = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('c03', b.about_personal)");
...
// the last string
$g_demographics_value_73 = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('g27', b.about_work)");
```

**Code:**

```
$shortcode = "SELECT COUNT(a.id) AS id FROM m_z_analytics a LEFT JOIN user_about b ON a.user_id=b.id WHERE";

$a_l_demographics = [17,2,10,2,3,12,27];
$a_p_demographics  = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
$a_c_demographics = min(count($a_l_demographics), count($a_p_demographics));

for ($i = 0, $k = 1; $i < $a_c_demographics, $k <= array_sum($a_l_demographics); $i++, $k++) {

  $demographics_values = 'g_demographics_value_'.$k;

  for ($j = 1; $j <= $a_l_demographics[$i]; $j++) {

    // $i here shows 00000000000000000112222222222334445555...

    $find_demographics = $a_p_demographics[$i] . str_pad($j, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

  }

  // $k is important for me to get value from the right rows in database. $k is based on array_sum($a_l_demographics)

  switch (true) {
    case $k <= 1:

      // from $find_demographics I should get for example `a01`, to use it later in FIND_IN_SET('a01', b.about_education)

      $$demographics_values = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('".$find_demographics."', b.about_education)");

      // I expect: $g_demographics_value_1['id'] have `a01` in FIND_IN_SET, $g_demographics_value_2['id'] `a02`...

      break;
    case $k <= 17:
      $$demographics_values = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('".$find_demographics."', b.about_personal)");
      break;
    case $k <= 36:
      $$demographics_values = $db->Query("$shortcode FIND_IN_SET('".$find_demographics."', b.about_work)");
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: If your code has `FIND_IN_SET` it's usually a sign your database schema isn't properly relational. Another thing to note is your use of `switch (true)` is a huge anti-pattern. Just use chained `if` statements or a look-up table.

Comment: Another huge warning sign is variables of the form `$x_1`, `$x_2` and so on. Instead `$x = array()` and append to that, indexing them like `$x[0]` and such. This is all [pretty elementary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) so if you're unfamiliar with how arrays work, experiment a little in some test code to get a feel for them.